# Ng-init from an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-ng-init

I have a list of products, you can see the JSON :

```
var panier =
    {
        "Client": "Ben",
        "Date":"",
        "Produits": [
            {
                "Id": "188", 
                "Name":"Name1",
                "Qte": "5", 
                "Variante": 
                "20 Pcs",
                "Prix" :"149.00"
            },
            {
                "Id": "231",
                "Name":"Name2",
                "Qte": "2", 
                "Variante": "7 encas de 35g",
                "Prix" :"109.00"
            },
            {
                "Id": "232", 
                "Name":"Name3",
                "Qte": "7", 
                "Variante": "10 pieces",
                "Prix" :"99.00"
            }
        ]
    };
```

I do a list with ionic to retrieve the products and it all works.

Inside of the list Item when I do (for example the firsr item) `Qte = {{product.Qte}}` it gives me `Qte = 5`

But when I want to put the quantity on a select it doesn't work with the ng-init :

```
<select 
    ng-model="selectedQte"
    ng-init="selectedQte = {{product.Qte}}"
    ng-options="selectedQte for selectedQte in range('10')"
    ng-change="product.Qte = selectedQte">
</select>
```

I have tried :

```
ng-init="selectedQte = product.Qte"
```

and :

```
ng-init="selectedQte = {{product.Qte}}"
```

But nothing happens. When I have tried :

```
ng-init="selectedQte = 3"
```

I have a `3`on my 3 selects.

But I want `5` on the first one, `2`on the second and `7`on the third.

Any help is needed, thanks !

Comment: This is not [the appropriate use for `ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#!).  `ng-init` is a directive, with a priority, which means it may or may not be initialized when other directives expect data to be available.  This sort of initialization should ***always*** be done in a controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the problem is with the `dataType` of the `Qte` in the JSON is `string` & the `array` created for range is sequence of `number`. You need to convert the JSON coming from response to `number` instead of `string` will do the trick. You could directly bind the `Product.Qte` to your `ng-model`.

**Markup**

```
<select ng-model="product.Qte"
    ng-options="selectedQte for selectedQte in range('10')">
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want the value of product.Qte, not the index.. Here in the example is 1,2,3. It can be : 2,6,3

Comment: Thanks @PankajParkar but I didn't get your answer. How can I convert the JSON to number ?

Comment: @aBennouna Cool & Cheers.. Glad to help you.Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<select ng-model="selectedQte" ng-init="selectedQte = panier.Produits[0]"
ng-options="item.Name for item in panier.Produits">
</select>
```

Your ng-model contains the selected value, however ng-option should iterate over your list. In your html you use selectedQte for both cases.

Comment: Nope sorry, it doesn't work. As I do a ng-repeat in a list 
`ng-repeat="product in cart.Produits"` 
The select will be repeated each time as it for selecting the quantity, I want each select to be initialized with the product quantity. That's why I did :
`ng-init="selectedQte = product.Qte"`

Comment: Can you please explain the behavior you want to achieve. So you want to have a dropdown with just numbers and based on it, to display the product with that quantity? Is that right?

Comment: @DianaR apologize for that..I mistakenly edited your post..And I rollbacked to the older version of it..

Comment: @PankajParkar ;) no worries

Comment: @DianaR In fact I have a cart with some products. I want to display a list with each product. On that list I want to have a dropdown with numbers (Quantity from 1 to 10) and this dropdown should be initialized with the value of product.Qte

Comment: Ok, then the explanation of @PankajParkar about dataType is what you should try to fix. In my understanding it was a different behavior than the one you described.